# Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Apparently it can be proven with a comparison but I've tried to compare it to $\frac{1}{n^{p}}$ with not results.

I've also tried comparing $\sqrt{n}$ with $\ln{n}$ but $\frac{1}{2^{\ln n}}$ diverges so that doesn't give me anything useful.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386878/does-the-series-sum-n-1-inftyx-sqrt-n-converge-pointwise-if-it-then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the comparison, it is enough to show that after a while $2^{\sqrt{n}}\gt n^2$.

Equivalently, we want to prove that after a while $(\ln 2)\sqrt{n}\gt 2\ln n$. There are various ways to do this. For example by using L'Hospital's Rule we can show that 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2\ln x}{(\ln 2)\sqrt{x}}=0.$$

Comment: I swear I tried the exact same thing and for some reason the $>$ was a $<$ instead. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k^2+1}^{(k+1)^2}\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k^2+1}^{(k+1)^2}\frac{1}{2^k}
<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k+1}{2^k}<\infty$$