# Convergence of $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am finding the positive values of $x$ for which the following series is convergent $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\sqrt{n}}$$  It is sure that it is not convergent for $x\geq1$ as $n$-th term will not tend to zero. Now $x\in[0,1)$ how to check its convergence? Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: For $x\geqslant1$, $x^{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge to $0$ hence the series diverges. For $x$ in $(0,1)$, using the bound $x^{\sqrt{n}}\leqslant x^k$ for every $k^2\leqslant n<(k+1)^2$ and every $k\geqslant1$ yields $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt{n}}\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k+1)x^k,$$ which should allow you to conclude.

Comment: right hand series $\sum (2N+1)x^{N}$ is convergent?

Comment: and $n$ is not fixed ....how its converges?

Comment: "right hand series ∑(2N+1)xN is convergent?" Yes. "and n is not fixed ....how its converges?" What?

Comment: See also: [Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x|^\sqrt n$ converge pointwise? If it then what would be the sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/386878)

Comment: @MartinSleziak ok thank you .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in ]0,1[$; then 
$$x^{\sqrt{n}} = \exp(\sqrt{n} \log x) = \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{n}|\log x|}} < \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^{3}}
$$
for large $n$, so by the comparison test the desired series converges.

Comment: how last inequality?

Comment: For all $a,b > 0$ we have $\xi^{a}/e^{b\xi} \to 0$ as $\xi \to \infty$, @neela

Comment: what is the role of $x\in[0,1)?$

Comment: @neela: Thanks; it makes exponential appear in the denominator, instead of the numerator.

Comment: yes yes .....thanks a lot....

Comment: how is the middle two terms are equal ?? @Nobody

Comment: @Prajakta, Note that $0 < x < 1$ :).

Comment: @Nobody Ohh yes right. I missed that.. :)

Answer (score 4):

*Without the exponential:*

If $0\le x <1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge1}x^{\sqrt n}&\le\sum_{n\ge1}x^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}=3x+5x^2+7x^3+9x^4+\dotsm \\
&\le 2+4x+6x^2+8x^3+10x^4+\dotsm=2(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\dotsm)\\
&= 2\biggl(\frac1{1-x}\biggr)'=\frac2{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}
hence the series converges.